# Searching three hyperlinks and outputting each on a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

Looking in the Column "U" unit ( 1 )  and the opposite of that cell in the Column "E"  extracting  hyperlink, then paste it on a new sheet (and so each unit)

I wrote a program , but it does not give needed result .

```
  Sub подготовительная()

  Dim r As Range
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim book1 As Workbook
  Dim str As String
  Dim gbr As Range

  Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\...\Вопрос.xlsx")
  'переходим в активную книгу на 1-ую страницу и выделяем диапозон
  book1.Worksheets("7").Activate

  Set rng = book1.Worksheets("7").Range("U33:U99")
  'находим первую 1
  Set r = rng.Find(What:="1")

  'запоминаем 1-ый адресс
  firstAddress = r.Address
  'другая переменная
  Set gbr = r.Offset(, -16)

  'забираем гиперссылку
  str = gbr.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
  'вставляем в Лист1
  book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Cells(1, 1).Value = str

  'ищем вторую 1
  book1.Worksheets("7").Activate
  Set r = r.FindNext(r)
  If r.Address <> firstAddress Then
      Set gbr = r.Offset(, -16)
      str = gbr.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
      book1.Worksheets("Лист2").Cells(1, 1).Value = str
  Else: Exit Sub
  End If

  'ищем третью 1
  book1.Worksheets("7").Activate
  Set r = r.FindNext(r)
  If r.Address <> firstAddress Then
      Set gbr = r.Offset(, -16)
      str = gbr.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
      book1.Worksheets("Лист3").Cells(1, 1).Value = str         
  Else: Exit Sub
  End If

  End Sub
```

Comment: Is it throwing any error? or its not resulting any output? did you debug the code? what exactly is happening?

Comment: Your code output first three elements from the range (E33:E99)  each on a new sheet ,but I need three elements from the range (E33:E99)  which are parallel elements in range (U33:U99) which value (1)

Comment: I realized what the problem is. There are only formulas in Column “U”. And the value of this formulas are (0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1).

Comment: Coud you recommend  anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistakes is in:

```
Set r = r.FindNext(r)
```

where you're trying to find the next occurrence if "1" in range `r` instead of `rng`

so you should use

```
Set r = rng.FindNext(r)
```

Furthermore you may want to shorten your code down with the use of a loop, a string array (where to store your three sheets names: "Лист1", "Лист2" and "Лист3") and some `With` statements, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim iLoop As Long
    Dim sheetNames(1 To 3) As String

    sheetNames(1) = "Лист1" '<--| change it with your actual 1st sheet name
    sheetNames(2) = "Лист2" '<--| change it with your actual 2nd sheet name
    sheetNames(3) = "Лист3" '<--| change it with your actual 3rd sheet name
    With Workbooks.Open(E:\...\Вопрос.xlsx").Worksheets("7").Range("U33:U99") '<--| open wanted workbook and refer to cells "U33:U99" in its worksheet "7"
        Set r = .Find(What:="1") '<--| the Find() method is called on the range referred to in the preceding With statement
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = r.Address
            Do
                iLoop = iLoop + 1 '<-- update loop counter
                .Parent.Parent.Worksheets(sheetNames(iLoop)).Cells(1, 1).value = r.Offset(, -16).Hyperlinks.item(1).Address '<--| write into proper worksheet whose name is taken from sheetNames array at index corresponding to current loop
                Set r = .FindNext(r) '<--| the FindNext() method is still called on the same range as in the preceding  .Find() statement
            Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress And iLoop < 3 '<--| exit loop if either you hit the first link or completed three loops
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```